# Avoid alarm firing after each reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My apps alarm fires directly after each reboot, not at the specified time and it's not repeating. The alarm I set is ignored.

InitializeAlarm:

```
public class InitialisiereAlarm extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "InitialisiereAlarm";

private static AlarmManager am;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    aktiviereAlarmDownload();
    finish();

  }

    private void aktiviereAlarmDownload() {
    Calendar calAkt = Calendar.getInstance();
    calAkt.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calAkt.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
    calAkt.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calAkt.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartAlarm.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarmCode", "12345");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calAkt.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

StartAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver, actually the same plus starting another activity:

```
public class StartAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "StartAlarm";
private WakeLock wl;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);  
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "SomeTag");
    wl.acquire();


    Intent intent2 = new Intent();
    intent2.setClassName("com.test.testApp",
            "com.test.testApp.DoThings");
    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent2);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345,
            intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calAkt = Calendar.getInstance();

    calAkt.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calAkt.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
    calAkt.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calAkt.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);


    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calAkt.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
}
```

StartAlarm in the Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".timer.StartAlarm"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Guess there's something I didn't understand... Any help is apprechiated!

**Edit:**
The problem was, that the alarm layed in the past. Solved it by setting the alarm to a future date by inserting

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

if (calAkt.compareTo(cal) <= 0) {
    calAkt.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 8);
}
```

Thanks @CommonsWare for the hint

Comment: What is d, stunde, minute? I don't see there declaration in BroadcastReceiver class. If they are nothing then as per this calAkt.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); it will fire on every boot.

Comment: These are variables. They are set correctly, I didn't put the belonging code in here, because it's large. I edited the code replacing these variables

Comment: Can you check with System.currentTimeMillis() + 20000 in setRepeating method instead calAkt.getTimeInMillis(). See if this fire after 20 seconds after boot.

Comment: I did try with 50 seconds, but that didn't work, too. The alarm started earlier

Answer (score 0):

> My apps alarm fires directly after each reboot

No, it does not. However, your `StartAlarm` `BroadcastReceiver` is getting control at boot time, because that is what you put in your manifest. If you do not want `StartAlarm` to get control at boot time, then get rid of its `<intent-filter>` in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but if I do that, the alarm isn't started at all after reboot.

Comment: @Schnicke: Then perhaps you should look at your `StartAlarm` `BroadcastReceiver` and decide which lines of its `onReceive()` method should run at boot time (which you might move to a separate `BroadcastReceiver` that you use with `BOOT_COMPLETED`), which ones should run when the alarm events occur, and which ones should be deleted altogether (such as your `WakeLock`).

Comment: Thank you, I already tried that before, the result was the same. All I want is the alarm not to be deleted after a reboot, but the alarm seems to be completely killed after a reboot except of the one time firing directly after reboot.

Comment: @Schnicke: "I already tried that before, the result was the same" -- then your previous try had a bug in your code, and you need to fix that bug. Beyond that, most of the code in `StartAlarm` is incorrect: don't create and `acquire()` a `WakeLock` on your own when you do not need it, don't use `setClassName()`, don't use an `Intent` for an `Activity` with `getBroadcast()` on `PendingIntent`, don't use `set()` on a `Calendar` without validating if your time is in the past, etc.

Comment: "don't use set() on a Calendar without validating if your time is in the past": That was a good hint, thanks.